# Casting Mongodb Document to Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript, mongodb

In my typescript express app, I am trying to retrieve a document from mongoDB and then cast that document to a type defined by an interface.

```
const goerPostsCollection = databaseClient.client.db('bounce_dev1').collection('goerPosts');
var currentGoerPosts = await goerPostsCollection.findOne({ goerId: currentUserObjectId }) as GoerPosts;
if (!currentGoerPosts) {
    currentGoerPosts = CreateEmptyGoerPosts(currentUserObjectId);
}
```

and the interface is defined like this

```
export interface GoerPosts {
    goerId: ObjectId;
    numPosts: number;
    posts: ObjectId[];
};
```

The code above has been working for me until I updated typescript from 4.4.4 to 4.5.2. Now the code no longer works and I get the error message:

```
[ERROR] 03:30:48 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
[posts] src/routes/create-post.ts(37,28): error TS2352: Conversion of type 'WithId<Document> | null' to type 'GoerPosts' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
[posts]   Type 'WithId<Document>' is missing the following properties from type 'GoerPosts': goerId, numPosts, posts
```

I can probably just revert back to 4.4.4, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this cleanly going forward.

Answer (score 28):

I had an issue with this too. The `toArray()` function returns a `WithId<Document>` type. You can extend this interface to get typescript to work.

```js
import type { WithId, Document } from 'mongodb'

interface GoerPosts extends WithId<Document> {
    goerId: ObjectId;
    numPosts: number;
    posts: ObjectId[];
}

var currentGoerPosts = (await goerPostsCollection.findOne({ goerId: currentUserObjectId }).toArray()) as GoerPosts;
```

### 2022 Update

You can pass the type to the collection

```
export interface GoerPosts {
    goerId: ObjectId;
    numPosts: number;
    posts: ObjectId[];
};

const currentGoerPosts = databaseClient.client.db('bounce_dev1').collection<GoerPosts>('goerPosts').findOne({ goerId: currentUserObjectId });
```

This will return `WithId<GoerPosts>` without the need to extend the `WithId` interface

Comment: I try the [mongodb tutorial on typescript](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial) and get the same error as OP. When I change to your code and convert the class to an interface in the model the tsc error disappears. But why `toArray()` if you `find one` which is an object and not array?

Comment: You can pass the type to `find()` too if you've put the collection in a variable: `const posts = goersPostsCollection.find<GoerPost>({}).toArray()`